# What is the syntax to select elements which have / dont have some string/regex in one of their attributes?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

I am trying to do this :

```
$em->createQueryBuilder('u')
->select('u')
->// where  u.username doesnt contain the string "desactive"
```

Also, I read [the querybuilder documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html), and I wonder if I should use the Expr class. 
But, the purpose of this class is very blur to me with as little explanation as this :

> To workaround some of the issues that add() method may cause, Doctrine created a class that can be considered as a helper for building expressions. This class is called Expr, which provides a set of useful methods to help build expressions:

Morevoer, is it me or is there no explanation at all about what some of its methods do ? (I am talking about the sections pseudo functions objects and functions objects)

Am I completely missing something :( ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test but you can use the 'notLike'

According to [doctrine query builder documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

**EDIT** : '%desactive%' **to** qb->expr()->literal('%desactive%')

```
$qb = $this->getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder();

return $qb->add('select','u')
          ->from('YOURBUNDLE:YOURENTITY','u')
          ->where($qb->expr()->notLike('u.username', qb->expr()->literal('%desactive%'))
          ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Comment: `->where($qb->expr()->notLike('u.username', '%desactive%'))` got me a mistake.
I changed it to  `->where($qb->expr()->notLike('u.username', $qb->expr()->literal('desactive%')))` following the syntax given in examples.

Now I dont have mistakes but I still have entities with "desactive" in their username.